# iOS 7.1 Airplay Mirroring with Microphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio-recording, airplay, mirroring

In iOS 7.1 Airplay Mirroring is not an option for apps that are actively using the microphone - either Airplay doesn't show up in control centre, or it does show up with only the device as output options. Turning on mirroring from the springboard and then launching the app allows mirroring to work correctly however.

- Is this a known issue (I filed a bug in any case: 16402749), or a deliberate move on Apple's part? I can't find any information to suggest either.
- Is there a workaround to this? I'd like users to be able to turn on Airplay Mirroring from inside the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS 7 Airplay options can be determined by the Audio Category you set (as discussed in [QA1803](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1803/_index.html)). Since I'm using `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` things should be working. This is probably a bug. Please dup if you're experiencing the same problem.

Comment: I've encountered this bug also. Airplay menu only shows device output options, even if I select airplay before launching the app. Any advice?

Comment: Our workaround was pretty clunky - if we detect the affected OS and show a dialog in the Airplay Help section of the app asking the user to start mirroring from the springboard. Haven't had a chance to see if it's fixed in iOS 8 yet, but if not I'll submit another bug report.